# password_verify and password_hash in php

Tags: php, passwords

I know that password_verify can be used to check a password's validity against a pre-stored hash. I'm also aware that password_hash requires us to choose a hashing algorithm such as `PASSWORD_ACTUAL` or `PASSWORD_BCRYPT`.

When `password_verify($pass, $hash)` converts `$pass` into hash how will it know which algorithm to use?

Comment: Where did you find `PASSWORD_ACTUAL`? I haven't seen that one in the docs.

Comment: @Don'tPanic he probably meant `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`

Comment: @ishegg Yeah, it seems likely, but I just wanted to ask in case I might be able to learn about something new.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can tell because the hash itself has the required information.

Per PHP documentation:

> Note that password_hash() returns the algorithm, cost and salt as part of the returned hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it. This allows the verify function to verify the hash without needing separate storage for the salt or algorithm information.

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

For example, a `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` hash would look like this:

```
$2a$10$N9qo8uLOickgx2ZMRZoMyeIjZAgcfl7p92ldGxad68LJZdL17lhWy
|-----|----------------------|------------------------------|
 A1,A2           B                            C
```

- A1: `2a` indicates the hash algorithm. For Bcrypt it's either `2a`, `2b`, or `2y`
- A2: `10` is the cost parameter of the hash. This makes the hash safe against timing attacks, since you can just increase this number to increase the "work" it's needed to compute
- B: this is the 128-bit salt
- C: the resulting 184-bit hash

With all those parameters (for now, just looking at `a1`) it can already tell what algorithm it is.

Comment: "algorithm, cost and salt" returned as part of the hash string?

Comment: Cleared up. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Hashes created using PASSWORD_BCRYPT have an identifier at the beginning: $2y$ and also makes sure the length of the hash is 60 characters. password_verify() most likely looks at one or both of these to determine what kind of hash to use.